# How to get the size of menu bar in pygtk?

Tags: python, user-interface, pygtk

I have a vbox in main window. Within the vbox is a menu and a fix. The fix is used to load image. I should change the size of main window according to the size of image. But I cannot find a way to get the size of menu bar. So the bottom part of the image cannot be displayed(I set the window unresizable).

I don't explicitly set the size of the menu. So it seems that all the functions ending with 'request' return -1.

How can I get the actual size of the menu bar? Or how can I display the image entirely?

Comment: you tried the `size_request()` method and it's result was -1?

Comment: try the `get_allocation()` of your menubar-widget. size-measurement in gtk is a hassle. (imho) Don't forget that your widget must be realized. It may be invisible, but it has to be associated to a screen...

Comment: @Don Question woooooooooooow~~ It works. Thank you very much. ;-)